# Validate Data completeness ETL

Tags: python, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, etl

Currently all database data is migrated from SQL/Oracle to snowflake( i.e. Extraction and Load only), basically a replica of Data so that later we can modify the data and Power Bi can fetch from Snowflake.

For now my requirement is to just validate if row and column count in tables between SQL and Snowflake is same i.e. validate data completeness for thousands or millions of records without a paid tool.

Since I have around 1000+Tables in database, I'm okay to run a python script to do the validation. Or Please suggest any other input that could help in achieving this.

Comment: Python script should be fine. I think it's more important to actually think about the strategy rather than tool.